# POST/PUT request to append row using Google Spreadsheet API returns 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

POST/PUT request to append a new row using Google Spreadsheet API returns 404 error.
Here is the API reference doc for append method in Google Spreadsheet API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

Below is the request & response. If the ':append' in the url path is removed, then the request works fine. But the new data overrides the existing row. Any idea what's wrong with this append request to add a new rows in the sheet

```
Request URL:https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1gpa0ByqgiDbGawyStfsJit8SdJfgi0rQsAAlzWkU7uM/values/**A2:append**?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:**404** 

Response Headers
status:404

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Authorization:Bearer xxxxxxx
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:chrome-extension://xxxxxxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
view source
{values: []}
values:[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293) on how to insert data to a google spreadsheet via POST or GET. You may also try the workaround given in this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/KzQ2T0391xo).

- Clear the [cache and cookies](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/32050).
- Try an [incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) or [private window](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fprivate-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH5YTK-xMxBa1T3e2zbtbk-KMA4Ew).
- Try another **browser** or **operating system**. (Here is a list of [supported configurations](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en).)
- Disable **browser plugins** or **extensions**. (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari instructions.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to make a REST API call from a chrome extension to append rows to a spreadsheet, which is access-restricted to the logged-in users. This tutorial is an App script and I'm not sure if this meets my requirement. Let me know if I am missing something.